# Open modal Bootstrap using jQuery: script is not opening modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I created two buttons and two modals: reserve a campsite (`id="reserveButton"` should open `id="reserveModal"`) and Log in (`id="loginButton"` should open `id="loginModal"`), and in the script file functions to open it. But it does not work. Please, help me to understand why it's not working. I thought maybe JS script was not correct, but I think I missed something in HTML file.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- build:css css/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Open+Sans" />

    <title>NuCamp: A Better Way To Camp</title>

</head>

<body>
    <header class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 align-self-center">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-fluid" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h1>NuCamp</h1>
                    <h2> a better way to camp</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-md-4 col-xl-2 align-self-right ">
                    <a role="button" class="btn-info btn btn-lg" id="reserveButton"
                        title="Or call us at <br /><strong>1-206-555-1234</strong>">Reserve Campsite</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div id="reserveModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Reserve a Campsite</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <form id="reserveForm">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 float-right">
                                    <label for="numCampers">Number of Campers</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <select class="col" id="numCampers">
                                            <option value="">Select...</option>
                                            <option>1</option>
                                            <option>2</option>
                                            <option>3</option>
                                            <option>4</option>
                                            <option>5</option>
                                            <option>6</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row form-group">
                                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 mb-4 float-right">
                                        <label for="DateChampers" class="col-form-label col-sm-6">Date</label>

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <label for="CampsiteType" class="col-form-label col-sm-6">Campsite Type</label>
                                    <div class="col-2 btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                                        <label class=" active btn btn-success">
                                            <input type="radio" name="siteType" id="option1" autocomplete="off">Tent
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="active btn btn-primary">
                                            <input type="radio" name="siteType" id="option2" autocomplete="off">RV
                                        </label>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <button type="Search" class="btn btn-primary ">Search</button>

                                    <button type="Cancel" class="btn btn btn-secondary "
                                        data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark sticky-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" height="30" width="30" /></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nucampNavbar">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nucampNavbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nucampNavbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Sites</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <span class="navbar-text ml-auto">
                        <a role="button" id="loginButton">
                            <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Login Modal-->
    <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Login</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="close" id="loginModal"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-12">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="loginEmail">Email address</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="loginEmail"
                                        placeholder="Enter email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-12">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="loginPassword">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="loginPassword"
                                        placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                                        <label class="form-check-label"> Remember me</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-auto"
                                    data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-1">Sign in</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
                <div id="homeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#homeCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#homeCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#homeCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/breadcrumb-trail.jpg"
                                alt="Breadcrumb Trail Campground" />
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Breadcrumb Trail Campground</h3>
                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Let Nucamp be your guide to this off-the-beaten-path,
                                    hike-in-only campground.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/react-lake.jpg" alt="React Lake Campground" />
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>React Lake Campground</h3>
                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Nestled in the foothills of the Chrome Mountains, this
                                    campgroundon the shores of pristine React Lake is a favorite for fly fishes.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/chrome-river.jpg" alt="Chrome River Campground" />
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Chrome River Campground</h3>
                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Spend a few sunny days and starry nights beneath a canopy
                                    of old-growth firs at this enchanting spot by the Chrome River.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#homeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#homeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>

                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carouselButton">
                        <i class="fa fa-pause"></i>
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
                <div class="col-sm-4 order-sm-last col-md-3">
                    <h2 class="text-sm-right">Discover & Review</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="media">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3 img-thumbnail" src="img/breadcrumb-trail-thumb.jpg"
                            alt="Breadcrump Trail thumbnal" />
                        <div class="media-body align-self-center">
                            <h3>Our Campsites</h3>
                            <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Explore our growing database of curated campsites and leave
                                your own reviews!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
                <div class="col-sm-4 order-sm-last col-md-3">
                    <h2>Featured Campsites</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="media">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3 img-thumbnail " src="img/react-lake-thumb.jpg"
                            class="rounded float-left" alt="Breadcrump Trail thumbnal" />
                        <div class="media-body align-self-center">
                            <h3>React Lake Campground</h3>
                            <p class="d-none d-sm-block"> Nestled in the foothills of the Chrome Mountains, this
                                campground on the shores of the pristine React Lake is a favorite for fly fishers.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 order-sm-last col-md-3">
                    <h2 class="text-sm-right">Our Community Partners</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="media">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3 img-thumbnail" src="img/bootstrap-thumb.png"
                            alt="Bootstrap Outfitters" />
                        <div class="media-body align-self-center">
                            <h3>Bootstrap Outfitters</h3>
                            <p class="d-none d-sm-block"> Bootstrap Outfitters supplies you with the gear you need at
                                prices you can't beat.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="site-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sites</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-5 text-center">
                    <h5>Social</h5>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-instagram" href="http://instagram.com/"><i
                            class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" href="http://facebook.com/"><i
                            class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/"><i
                            class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google" href="http://youtube.com/"><i
                            class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                    <a role="button" class="btn btn-link" href="tel:+12065551234"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        1-206-555-1234</a><br />
                    <a role="button" class="btn btn-link" href="mailto:campsites@nucamp.co"><i
                            class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> campsites@nucamp.co</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- build:js js/main.js -->
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

</body>

</html>
```

**Scripts.js**

```
$(function () {
    $(".carousel").carousel({ interval: 2000 });
    $("#carouselButton").on('click', function () {
        if ($("#carouselButton").children("i").hasClass("fa-pause")) {
            $(".carousel").carousel("pause");
            $("#carouselButton").children("i").removeClass("fa-pause");
            $("#carouselButton").children("i").addClass("fa-play");
        } else {
            $(".carousel").carousel("cycle");
            $("#carouselButton").children("i").removeClass("fa-play");
            $("#carouselButton").children("i").addClass("fa-pause");
        }
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#reserveButton').on('click', function () {
        $('#reserveModal').show();
    });



    $('#loginButton').on('click', function () {
        $('#loginModal').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

1. You have 2 elements with ID `loginModal`.  HTML IDs must be unique.  Change the button with that ID to use a different ID.
2. [The Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#via-javascript) show how to open modals in v5.  You need to initialise it before you can call `.show()` on it:

   ```
   // First instantiate your modal
   const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal('#myModal', {
       keyboard: false
   });

   // Now show it
   myModal.show();
   ```

Working snippet below.

Note - please take some time to [create a **minimal** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem - 90% of the HTML and JS in your question is not related to the problem, and it just takes extra time to sift through it trying to find the actual problem.  If you do this before you post your question, you make it so much easier and faster for others to help.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#reserveButton').on('click', function() {
    const reserveModal = new bootstrap.Modal('#reserveModal', {});
    reserveModal.show();
  });

  $('#loginButton').on('click', function() {
    const loginModal = new bootstrap.Modal('#loginModal', {});
    loginModal.show();

  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a role="button" class="btn-info btn btn-lg" id="reserveButton" title="Or call us at <br /><strong>1-206-555-1234</strong>">Reserve Campsite</a>

<div id="reserveModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Reserve a Campsite</h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <form id="reserveForm">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 float-right">
                <label for="numCampers">Number of Campers</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <select class="col" id="numCampers">
                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 mb-4 float-right">
                  <label for="DateChampers" class="col-form-label col-sm-6">Date</label>

                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">

                <label for="CampsiteType" class="col-form-label col-sm-6">Campsite Type</label>
                <div class="col-2 btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <label class=" active btn btn-success">
                                        <input type="radio" name="siteType" id="option1" autocomplete="off">Tent
                                    </label>
                  <label class="active btn btn-primary">
                                        <input type="radio" name="siteType" id="option2" autocomplete="off">RV
                                    </label>

                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">

                <button type="Search" class="btn btn-primary ">Search</button>

                <button type="Cancel" class="btn btn btn-secondary " data-dismiss="modal">Cancel
                                </button>

              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a role="button" id="loginButton">
  <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login
</a>

<!--Login Modal-->
<div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Login</h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" id="NOT-loginModal"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <form>
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label class="sr-only" for="loginEmail">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="loginEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label class="sr-only" for="loginPassword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="loginPassword" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                  <label class="form-check-label"> Remember me</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel
                            </button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-1">Sign in</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- build:js js/main.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZwqZIVdD3iXNyGHbSYdsmWP//UBokj2FHAxKuSBKDSo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-2rNj2KJ+D8s1ceNasTIex6z4HWyOnEYLVC3FigGOmyQCZc2eBXKgOxQmo3oKLHyfcj53uz4QMsRCWNbLd32Q1g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```